# How to limit the number of records displayed in a cross reference field in RSA ARCHER?

Tags: cross-reference, archer

My current cross reference field show all the record references it gets in Child records. I want to limit it to 5. How can this be done in RSA archer

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the application/ questionnaire where your field exists. Within the cross reference field you’d like to update, navigate to the option tab and all the way at the bottom there is a ‘Configuration’ section. Within that there is a ‘Default Records Display’ with values ranging from 5-50 ( in increments of 5) and All. Changing your cross references to 5 should achieve what you’re looking to do.

Comment: Awesome!  For some reason I was thinking of the record lookup and not the actual displaying of the records.

Answer (score 0):

Well Gupta, that depends on if you can filter the records down to a specific amount.  Currently Archer cannot just return the "top 5" records.